# How to send mail to users in laravel when the last record executes?

Tags: php, laravel

There are two types of records in my database one is unique and the other is duplicate. I delete unique records when they execute and only duplicate records executes. I want to send mail to a user about the duplicate and unique count of records. how can I achieve this?
The mail is sending every time the record executes but I want to send mail only when the last record executes with all the counts of duplicate and unique records.

Comment: what records do you need to count ?
unique or duplicate ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, would you please clarify more about your question?

Comment: Which part of the problem are you struggling with specifically?